# Non-legacy animation cannot be stopped / controlled

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I made an animation using Animation panel, which swaps images from time to time. Read from the Internet, this is not a legacy animation.

Here is the Animation panel screenshot:

[image: Animation Panel]

Then, I add the **Animation** and **Animator** components to the Game Object and assign the animation, which is called `Animation01`, to it. Here is the screenshot from Inspector of the Game Object:

[image: Inspector Panel]

I try to use the following C# script to stop the animation :

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 public class Scene1 : MonoBehaviour {
     public GameObject ball;
     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         ball.animation.Stop();
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {

     }
 }
```

but the animation didn't stop. It prompts a notice in Console:

> Default clip could not be found in attached animations list.

What did I miss?

---

**UPDATE**: By disabling/ removing Animator component, the animation is stopped and cannot be controlled by codes. I need to control the animation by codes.

Comment: Also, I have to notice: this question is remarkably better written that a majority of questions on `unity3d` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity had implemented two animation systems throughout it's history. **Animation** component belongs to the [legacy animation system](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Animations.html), while **Animator** component belongs to the [new animation system](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimationOverview.html). So, adding both components makes no sense: you either use the old system or the new.

The main difference between the legacy and new animation system is that the new animation system is much more advanced in way it's controlled. However, it also means that it's more complicated. It adds another level of abstraction: instead of launching animation yourself, you control variables that influence the behaviour of a special state machine, [animation controller](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AnimatorControllers.html).

So, if you want to use animations for something really, really simple, where you want just to launch animations manually, it may be better to use legacy animation system instead. But the components are not the only thing that is different: the animation files themselves are marked to determine if they are "legacy" or not. By default, when you create an animation in the new unity version, it belongs to the new animation system. If you want to use it with a legacy animation, you have to mark it as a legacy animation. Unfortunately, [you'll have to do a little hack to achieve that](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/577801/animation-must-be-marked-as-legacy.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to mark the animation as legacy (no point to do so). I disabled the Animation component, and I can see the Animator is working (the progress bar is moving). However, how can I control the "Animation Controller" via code, e.g. stop the animation?

Comment: As I said, "Animation Controller" adds another layer of abstraction, so your code doesn't have to include concepts of individual animations anymore if you use it. Instead, you modify the Animation Controller's external parameters, and the controller itself decides what state to switch to, and different states can have different animations attached to them. Here's a good tutorial: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/animation/animator-controller

Comment: Thanks. Alternatively, I managed to start / stop the animation by enabling and disabling the Animator component .

Comment: You can certainly do that, but it is a hack. Also, if you only want to control a single animation, just start and stop it, then I would use legacy animation system. Animator is just an overkill for such a situation.