# Enabling Animator causes flicker?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Unity 3D (2D mode), I have a few Game Objects linked with Animator, and animation made with Animation Timeline. The animation is initially disabled:

```
public GameObject car;
Animator carAnim;
void Start() {
  carAnim = car.GetComponent<Animator>();
  carAnim.enabled = false;
}
```

Then, with an input event, the animation is set to enable:

```
void Update() {
  if(Input.GetKeyDown(0)) {
    carAnim.enabled = true;
  }
}
```

However, when the animation starts to play, the whole screen flickers once. How to remove the flicker?

Comment: Could you check your animation timeline start values. It might be possible that when you started recording the animation then the position of screen or game objects might have shifted by mistake.

Comment: I double checked all animations. They have keyframes at 0 second. Worth to mention is, the part without animation ( e.g. background ) flickers too. This happens in Unity Editor & on iOS .

Comment: Having keyframes at 0 second isnt the issue but the initial values of game object at 0 keyframe as for me it doesnt flicker whenever I start an animation try to export its package to a device and run. If the package runs well on device then its your graphic card problem probably.

Comment: Your animation changes only sprites or does it change any other properties in timeline? Any events attached to the start of the animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're trying to enable and disable Animator component at runtime. Animator was not designed to be used like this. If you want to play animation in certain point of time, just keep Animator enabled, create 2 states - "Idle" and "YourAnimation", create transition between them and control it with some bool parameter.

Much simple way is to use Animation component (if you don't need Mecanim and transitions between states), where you can play animation with just one line of code:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("MyAnimation");
```

Comment: FYI, there is no Animation component at all. Using Animation component will cause warnings and animation cannot be controlled. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30091098/188331)

Comment: Then you should properly setup your states and transition in Mecanim, and don't touch "enabled" property of Animator component. For more info [go here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StateMachineBasics.html)